# Single IP to access Kubernetes cluster ingress

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, ingress, amazon-eks

I have an amazon EKS cluster that I'm using to host multiple websites, I have an ingress controller and a load balancer that spins up more pods as needed.

I normally use CNAME type "eg alias or aname" to point a domain to the dynamic cluster, however, I'm dealing with wanting to move to an A record long term for more dns compatibility etc.

Is there any service within AWS or other tools other than F5 BIG IP that I could use to use a single static IP to point to my cluster?

Comment: I should add the thought of pointing a static IP at an EC2 instance that redirects to the cluster has crossed my mind but then I'm adding a potential bottleneck before the load balancer thus making it useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an "AWS Golbal Accelerator" to do this, ended up running faster however the other way did work. It allowed me to point a static IP to my network load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably combine Network Load balancer with App load balancer

Please refer to the article at [Single IP to access Kubernetes cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)
Please let me know if I misunderstood the question

Comment: This Looks like it could be the way to go, not sure how I couldn't find this article. Ill give it a go and report back with how I go.